# is_array returning FALSE when array is provided

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to convert a multidimensional object into an array to pass into an API call that requires an array. Problem is, even after converting the object to array using the lazy method of:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($object),true)
```

The returned value is acting funny. I'm getting empty array values where values should be none, so I tried running it through a foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $data_each ) {

    if ( is_array($data_each[$key]) ) { $data[$key] = NULL; }

}
```

But it's not catching the array value in the foreach loop. After running the foreach, I check the value that I happen to KNOW is coming back as an empty array and as long as I check using in_array outside the foreach loop is is catching it as an array. But not within the loop for some reason.

What am I missing?

Comment: please share your json

Comment: ^ and/or `var_dump($data_each);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $data_each ) {
    if ( is_array($data_each[$key]) ) { $data[$key] = NULL; }
}
```

Here, `$data_each` is a value of `$data[$key]`. Try `is_array($data_each)` if you want to check whether the value is an `array` or not. In the loop `$data_each` is same as `$data[$key]`.

Comment: Got it!! Man, I've been awake too long. Thanks a million!

Comment: You are welcome, btw, me too awaking for the whole knight and it's time to go to bed because it's `8:12` of morning :-)